# Clarification on comments policy?

Tags: discussion, site-policies, comments

Can we have a clarification on what is and is not acceptible for discussion in comments?

Based on [this question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1383/how-should-we-discourage-extended-discussion-in-comments) and its responses, I can see it may be policy to redirect extended comment discussions that have got away from the question/answer to chat.  Putting aside my particular thoughts on how exactly this could be done, having looked at some of the cited examples, I can see it's a good idea to try to do this.

However, I've just found that a comment I made, specifically on the content of [an answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31720/can-the-recent-re-released-ds-games-such-as-mario-kart-ds-already-show-some-3d-ef/31724#31724), and two comments refuting it, have been deleted with an admonishment not to "pollute answers with extended discussions". I don't see either how three comments qualifies as "extended", or how commenting specifically on the content of the answer is "side-tracked".

(Of course, since I can't see the comments any more, it's possible that many other comments were made and everything got off-track since I last visited, but... I doubt it.)

If there is a policy on this, can we have it here or in the FAQ?

Answer (score 2):

The comments degraded into extended speculation ("You need extra code!" "That doesn't mean they can't!" "But they haven't!" "But they could!" "They wouldn't!" "Why!" etc.); perhaps a few comments too many have been deleted, but I agree with your original point and removed the point about how the 3D effect works from the answer.

Comment: Well... That's fair enough. (And fair to say I probably would have weighed in on the "But they could/'nt!" argument if I'd been about, and been fairly deleted for it, heh.) Still, if that meta discussion resulted in a policy, better to have it listed somewhere official-like.